# Discord.js PM doesn't work for only 1 person

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So, When my bot warns a user for spamming it also sends a private message. This has worked all day for everyone and now it gives me a UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send messages to this user error for one person in my guild for all the other people it works. (It did work earlier today for this person too)

```
target.send(embed);
```

The target is a GuildMember{}.

Maybe it has anything to do with async and await?

The error code:

```
(node:14036) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send messages to this user
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:170:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:14036) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:14036) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Just to clearify this only happens for one specific user.

Comment: It just means they blocked the bot or they have dms from non-friends turned off. The best thing you can do is add a `catch` block.

Comment: The weird thing is that the person says she changed nothing about her settings and earlier today it did send the messages. @Lioness100 But let me ask her to change the setting.

Comment: After the settings were changed it did work thank you!